# decoding typescript ternary operator

Tags: javascript, typescript

I came across some code in the typescript docs that is confusing for me.

```
function compare(a: string, b: string): -1 | 0 | 1 {
  return a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Can anybody explain what's going on in the return statement? Is that a ternary operator?

Comment: It's not typescript-specific, just https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator twice.

Comment: This is why I don't approve ternary operations in PRs at work. This is a nested ternary and they become very difficult to read very quickly. It's saying if a is equal to b, return 0, otherwise if a is greater than b, return 1, otherwise return -1. (note: a > b in strings is a sorting check)

Comment: WHile I do like ternary operations - I don't like them to be nested. YOu should avoid nested ternary as much as possible

Comment: From type system perspective `compare` function (I believe it is a callback for sort) returns `-1` OR `0` OR `1`

Comment: There’s a shorter and more general way to write this: `(b < a) - (a < b)`. Not sure if TypeScript allows subtracting booleans, but `Number(b < a) - Number(a < b)` should do.

Comment: See [Alternative to nested ternary operator in JS](/q/32289340/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it like this:

```js
function compare(a: string, b: string): -1 | 0 | 1 {
  return a === b ? 0 : (a > b ? 1 : -1);
}
```

If `a === b`, return 0. Otherwise, is `a > b`? If so, return 1. Otherwise, return -1. Might be easier to think of like this:

```js
function compare(a: string, b: string): -1 | 0 | 1 {
  if (a === b) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    if (a > b) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
}
```

Although that's the way I *think* about it, this is the way I'd write the code with if statements (remember, all three of these are equivalent):

```js
function compare(a: string, b: string): -1 | 0 | 1 {
  if (a === b) {
    return 0;
  } else if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function compare(a: string, b: string): -1 | 0 | 1 {
  return a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1;
}
```

First, analyze the declared return type `-1 | 0 | 1`:

This is a union of Literal types [[see docs for reference]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types). This indicates that the return type of this function will be either:

- the number `-1`,
- the number `0`,
- or the number `1`.

Now analyze the `return` statement in the function `return a === b ? 0 : (a > b ? 1 : -1);`:

This is a 'nested' JavaScript Ternary Operator [[see docs for reference]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

The expression before the `?` is evaluated first; If it is evaluated to `true` then the expression before the `:` is evaluated, if `false` then the expression after the `:` is evaluated.

It is equivalent to the follow `if` statement:

```
if (a === b) {
  return 0;
} else {
  if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  {
}
```

or put more simply:

```
if (a === b) {
  return 0;
} else if (a > b) {
  return 1;
} else {
  return -1;
{
```